# Nginx and chroot users - Permission denied

Tags: nginx, chroot

I use nginx 1.4.4 and I created a chrooted user. This user can only see his /home/user folder, and I created in a "www" folder.

I put in my virtual host file :

```
root /home/user/www;
```

But I have an error :

```
*1 stat() "/home/crm/www/" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

I try to put chmod 777 on home, home/user, home/user/www, but I got the error.

I took a look on this question : [nginx + PHP-FPM = "permission denied" error 13 in nginx log; configuration mistake?](https://serverfault.com/questions/170192/nginx-php-fpm-permission-denied-error-13-in-nginx-log-configuration-mista/551505#comment668962_551505), but I can't change owner the www folder.

How can I correct this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add your user to www-data group (Nginx should run as www-data).

Comment: Or chown www to user:www-data. (with r option).

Answer (score 0):

Ok a lot of chmod after... I achieve what I wanted ! I got an other error on :

My config (namei -om /home/crm/www) :

```
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxr-xr-x root root crm
drwxrwxrwx crm  sftp www
```

And I have another error too on :

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $request_filename;
```

The filename was bad an make an "file not found error" too.